# Fitch Biconditional Proof Help?

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

[image]

Hi, I'm starting to learn formal proofs using Fitch, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out my arguments. I've generally mapped out the subproofs I was considering to use, but I'm unsure how to proceed from this point.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Always raise a context with what needs to be discharged to deduce the target.  Thusly, when aiming to *introduce an universal* quantifier, you need to begin the subproof by assuming an *arbitrary term*.  In this case, twice.

Assume the arbitrary terms, [a], and [b], *somehow* derive the biconditional (hint: several universal eliminations will be involved), then introduce two universals.

```
|  Ɐx Ɐy (Indiff(x,y)→Indiff(y,x))        Premise
|_ :
|  :
|  |_ [a]                                 Assumption
|  |  |_ [b]                              Assumption
|  |  |  Ɐx Ɐy (Indiff(x,y)→Indiff(y,x))  Reiteration
|  |  |  :
|  |  |  Indiff(a,b)↔Indiff(b,a)          Biconditional Introduction
|  |  Ɐy (Indiff(a,y)↔Indiff(y,a))        Universal Introduction
|  Ɐx Ɐy (Indiff(x,y)↔Indiff(y,x))        Universal Introduction
■
```

Filling in the middle should not be too hard. It looks like your checker requires biconditional introduction to look thus:

```
h|  |_ X    Assumption
:|  |  :
k|  |  Y    Somehow derived
 |  +
n|  |_ Y    Assumption
:|  |  :
m|  |  X    Somehow derived
 |  X ↔ Y   Biconditional Introduction (h-k,n-m)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a different proof checker, but perhaps seeing how the goal is reached here may help to make this work with the proof checker you are using.

This proof checker has a different way of accepting well-formed formulas. I replaced "Indiff" with "I".

I also noticed that the goal was simply "∀x∀y(Ixy↔Iyx)", that is, "∀x∀y(Indiff(x,y) ↔ Indiff(y,x)", and you had as the fifth premise "∀x∀y(Ixy → Iyx)", that is, "∀x∀y(Indiff(x,y) → Indiff(y,x)". I only needed to use that premise and so I did not include the others.

[image]

To get a biconditional I had to start two conditional subproofs. The first one I assumed "Iab" on line 2 and reached the goal of that subproof, "Iba", on line 5. The second subproof I went in the opposite direction and assumed "Iba" on line 6 and reached the goal "Iab" on line 9. Within each subproof I eliminated the universal quantifier, but using names for the "x" and "y" variables that helped me reach the conclusion.

When I introduced the biconditional on line 10 this discharged the assumptions on lines 2 and 6.

A description of the rules are in *forallx* (link below). For universal elimination (∀E) see pages 239-240. For conditional elimination (→E) see pages 103-104. For biconditional introduction (↔I) see pages 111-112. For universal introduction (∀I) see pages 243-246.

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/